# Class not registered error when trying to use COM (even from 32 bit process)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, com

I need to use a 3rd party COM library to interact with an API. It seems to have installed ok, and there is a test harness that has been provided to me that seems to work OK, so I'm sure there's nothing wrong with the DLL.

My .NET code looks like this (in vs 2015):

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("xxxxx")); //this works ok
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(t); // this throws an error
```

The error thrown is:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: `Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {xxxxx} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).`
```

I have ensured all projects including the main one are x86 (as I know the DLL is a 32 bit lib):

[image: 32 bit]

For good measure, I tried to re-register the lib like this: `Regsvr32 xxxx.dll /s` but still getting the same error.

Any help would be great! Thanks.

**EDIT**

The main project is indeed set to x86, "prefer 32 bit" is therefore greyed out.

[image]

Comment: The platform name is completely irrelevant in C# projects.  The only settings that matters are the jitter forcing options in Project > Properties > Build tab (Platform target and Prefer 32-bit).  And only the settings for the EXE project, that's the one that locks in the bitness of the process.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor if that doesn't help, as described in the *many* existing Q+A for this exception.

Comment: Why the downvote? I realise there's lots of same questions, all of which have the same answer (32 bit vs 64) - which as far as I can see I've set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you might have the wrong GUID. Run regsvr32.exe mydll.dll. As Hans suggests, run process monitor during the registry registration and check to make sure you have the right CLSID

Comment: Can you edit your answer to highlight that is was indeed the wrong CLSID?